# Is better to have date dimension to loaded SQL or generated with DAX

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

We are working with a warehouse based on MSSQL. It is populated with a daily SSIS job.

For reports we use Power BI.

Our current implementation has date dimension table implemented and generated with DAX. Date dimension table is basically a table with dates generated from X date to 20 years in the future and some additional columns (Quarter, Year, Fiscal Quarter, Fiscal Year, Month) for filtering.

We are considering doing this generation of date dimension on the SQL side. What I'm trying to understand are pros vs cons of generating this table in DAX or loading this from SQL server? Especially in respect to performance.

Thanks!

Comment: The best practice is to use database for building all elements of the data model, and use DAX for measures.

Comment: It is a lot easier to do it on the database side, particularly when generating fiscal years that are not Jan to Dec calendar, the code is easier to maintain and you are not have to copy the dax into other reports.

Comment: Both comments make much sense and make the SQL side better pick - from consistency and cleanliness perspective. I suppose performance difference of both approaches is negligible?